# OpenCV Viz - Initialize Camera Position

Tags: c++, opencv

How do I initialize the camera such that the scene in 3D is viewed like the image in 2D ?

When I run my program, the camera starts off far off from the scene with its translation and rotation parameters wrong (second figure). I have to do a lot of dragging and scrolling before I get it to a decent but still wrong position and viewing angle (third figure). I would like the camera to be initialized and viewing the 3D scene just like in the 2D image in the first figure.

I could try functions such as but I would need the parameters which I don't know. Would it be the origin ?

[image]

space

[image]

[image]